# How to get details (Position ,Rotation, Scale) of the Game Object that is placed in real world as AR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

When I place a game object (e.g.: Cube) in the real world with the help of AR using Unity, I want to receive detail of that game object like the position, rotation and scale in xyz plane separately. Will it be possible to get it in text form?

Comment: In what form do you want the pose of the gameobject? Is the Debug Console enough, or do you want it printed to a file?

Comment: It will be better to get in string format as I have to show it in UI Text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get position, rotation and scale separately would be like this:

```
Vector3 worldPosition = this.transform.position;
string worldPositionStr = worldPosition.x + ", " + worldPosition.y + ", " + worldPosition.z;
```

assuming the script is attached to the object in question.
For rotation use `this.transform.eulerAngles` instead of `this.transform.position` and `this.transform.lossyScale` for scale (have a look at the documentation of each of those fields to better understand them).

You should keep in mind though that these values are in the space of the current AR session. So these values depend on where you start the AR session and might change each time you restart your session.

Comment: If I want to take individual string for individual value like,  string worldPositionX = worldPosition.x; , it will give me only the x value, right?

Comment: yes, exactly. The plus in between the x, y, z are used to put the strings together into a new string that will show all three dimension values.